# Exporting org-mode to HTML: In-place coloring

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

How can I specify the color for a piece of text that Emacs Org-Mode should use when exporting the file to HTML?

e.g.

```
* Here is one bullet
  ** Here is another bullet
       Here is some text that I want in BOLD RED 
       Here is some other text that I want in the default face
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't say if this is a one-off or not. css stylesheet makes sense if you need styles. To just do what you describe once, you can include the HTML directive for red in your org file, as follows:

```
Here is some text that I want in *@@html:<font color = "red">@@BOLD RED@@html:</font>@@*
```

See the section **Quoting HTML tags** in the Org manual.

Answer (score 7):

Jeffrey gave the answer. However, to add extra information, please know that I'm busy making an org-macros project on GitHub, with the goal of making such behaviors a breeze.

The project is still in draft (the macros won't export correctly to LaTeX), full doc is not yet available (while it's OK, but you should look at the Org source for the real usage syntax, though), but if you clone https://github.com/fniessen/org-macros, you should be able to use either the "bgcolor", the "color" or the "highlight" macro (after INCLUDE'ing the org-macros.setup file in your Org document).

You would write:

```
INCLUDE: path/to/org-macros.setup

Here is some text that I want in *{{{color(red, BOLD RED)}}}*.
```

When I'll have those macros in a finished state, they will work for both HTML and LaTeX (at least).

Comment: This solution is limited in that you cannot use large blocks of text in place of `BOLD RED`. Perhaps there is an argument length limitation in macros.

Comment: I agree that it's certainly not the best way for large blocks of text, or for several paragraphs.

Comment: In that case, you'd better use special blocks such as #+begin_bgcolor..#+end_bgcolor and define those in LaTeX/HTML/etc.

Comment: You have such examples for #+begin/end_info / warning / tip / error in my document.

Comment: This github repo helped me understand what was necessary to beautify an org mode document. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a custom css stylesheet linked to your exported html document by using the HTML HEAD option:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
```

Take a look at the exported html and the classes that get assigned to different org levels and you should be able to put together a fairly simple stylesheet in no time. There's a good example of one here: https://gist.github.com/mowen/326524

Here is a reference: http://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html#CSS-support

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

```
* Here is one bullet
** Here is another bullet
#+begin_html 
Here is some text that I want in <span style='color:red'>BOLD RED</span>
#+end_html
Here is some other text that I want in the default face
```